# Store - save - fetch/retreive array value (php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm having a hard time of thinking how am I going to save the values taken from the checkbox (came from "modalForm").
I have 2 forms here. My "mainform" and "modalForm".

This codes are similar to my program, I just replace the values.

My program works like this. I have a search bar before this, searching unique id and after searching it, their details will be loaded here.

1. If you click the textbox, a modal will pop up containing checkboxes. If one checkbox is checked, its label beside it will be the one to be shown on the textbox. When two or more checkbox were checked, a word "multiple" will be shown in the UI.
   Value(s) will be inserted/updated to the database.

In my case here, instead of label, value is the one showing on the textbox.

2. Can you help me how can I store the array that i used into database and how can I fetch their values once it was loaded again.

My working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8bf3vjuk/

I'm having a hard time here because here are two forms.

**testing.php**

```
<form method="post" name="mainform" action="">
    <label>Sports</label>
    <a href="#modal" id="done"> <!-- when the input textbox was clicked, modal will pop up -->
        <input disabled type="text" id="test" name="test" placeholder="test" value="">
        <input class="hb_button3" type="submit" id="modalbutton" value="save"> <!-- once submit value taken on the checkbox will be save to the system database -->
    </a>
</form>

<form method="post" name="modalForm" id="modalForm" action="testing.php">
    <div class="modalwrapper" id="modal">   <!-- modal -->
            <div class="modalcontainer">    
                <div class="modalcol1">
                    <label>Basketball </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="test_modal[]" name="test_modal[]" value="1">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label>Baseball </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="test_modal[]"  name="test_modal[]" value="2">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label>Soccer </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="test_modal[]" name="test_modal[]" value="3">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label>Volleyball </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="test_modal[]" name="test_modal[]" value="4">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <label>DOTA :)</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="test_modal[]" name="test_modal[]" value="5">
                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <div class="savebutton">
                        <input class="btn1" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>      
</form>
```

here is my **styles.css**

```
/* modal layout */
    .modalwrapper {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        visibility: hidden;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    }

    .modalwrapper:target {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible
    }

    .overlay {
        background-color: #000;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        height: 100%;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .modalcontainer {
        display: table;
        background-color: #777;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 100;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .modalcol1 { display: table-cell; }

    .clear { clear: both; }

    .modalwrapper input[type=checkbox] {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .savebutton input[type=submit] {
        float: right;
        background-color: maroon;
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
    /* modal layout ends here */
```

my **javascript** code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#done").click(function(e) {
                    // alert('ok');
                 $("#modal").fadeIn();
                // e.preventDefault();
                 });
            $("#submit").click(function(e) {

                var checked = [];
                i=0;
                temp=""
        $("input[name='test_modal[]']:checked").each(function ()
        {   temp=$(this).val();
            i++;
           checked.push($(this).val());
        });
        if (i==1)
              $("#test").val(temp);        
          else if (i>1)
              $("#test").val('multiple');
              else if (i==0)
              $("#test").val('nothing');
                         $("#modal").fadeOut();  
                        // alert($("#do").val())
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Hope you can help me guys. If you guys can suggest to replace my javascript by using any php statement like if condition, I will try to test it.
Many thanks.

Comment: For the next time. Please have an eye on your spelling.

Comment: updated, im sorry.